# jQuery - show only current ul (using a tags as the click rather than li's)

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle, html-lists, children

I am trying to show/hide child `ul's` in the following navigation. I managed to get it working with the help of Aleksi Yrttiaho.

I then realised that I hadn't coded the list items as links in my jsFiddle, and as soon as I did the function broke, can someone help me out get it working again?

**[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dh8j/13/) is the correct markup but with the function not working**

**[This is the old markup](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dh8j/11/) (pre a tags essentially) and you can see it working**

So the only difference is that I want the function to run on the click of a link, rather than a click of the li.

Many thanks,
Red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try

```
$("nav li").find("ul").hide().end().find("a")
// hide all other ul's in the nav
.click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).parent().children('ul').delay(200).fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/866UZ/

Answer (score 0):

In your markup you should enclose all the li's inside `nav` in a `ul` tag. Because li's should always be inside a `ul` tag. And your selector is also `nav ul li` which will look for `ul` tag inside `nav` thats whay it was not working as expected.

Take a look at this working demo I have fixed it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Dh8j/24/